# Why can't I trace syscalls made by `/bin/echo`?

Tags: macos, bsd, dtrace

I was wondering what syscalls are made by `echo` (the command, not the shell built-in), so I decided to snoop it via dtrace. Specifically I used [`dtruss`](http://dtrace.org/blogs/brendan/2011/10/10/top-10-dtrace-scripts-for-mac-os-x/).

Consider that the following works (tracing all syscalls made by `sed`):

```
 sudo dtruss /usr/local/bin/sed 's/a/e/' <<< 'cat'
SYSCALL(args)        = return
thread_selfid(0x0, 0x0, 0x0)         = 470642 0
# and many more…
```

But if I try the same with `echo`, I get the following:

```
 sudo dtruss /bin/echo 'cat'
dtrace: failed to execute /bin/echo: unknown error
```

In fact: there are *many* commands with which I get this error. The commonality is that those commands were all in `/bin` or `/usr/bin`.

[Brendan's blog](http://dtrace.org/blogs/brendan/2011/10/10/top-10-dtrace-scripts-for-mac-os-x/) suggests that it is possible to use `dtruss` on commands such as `ls` (his example is `sudo dtruss ls -l hfsslower.d`, where `hfsslower.d` is a normal text file). The blog post was written in 2011, concerning Mac OS X. But I am aware that OS X has had various security enhancements since then.

Could it be that I am bumping into OS X security of some sort? I am using OS X 10.12 Sierra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I should've tried searching the error message.

[Looks like it is indeed System Integrity Protection](http://internals.exposed/blog/dtrace-vs-sip.html).

> You can no longer attach DTrace to «restricted» processes on your Mac. And by «restricted» I mean every single built-in utility, daemon or application.

My interpretation of the article is:

- `csrutil enable --without dtrace` is not sufficient to attach DTrace to built-in executables
- You need instead to do a full `csrutil disable` (this turns off SIP completely, which is overkill and creates a gap in your security, but seems to be the only solution)